# Cambio del gráfico al momento de pasar de ggplot a plotly

Tags: r

Al momento de crear el gráfico en ggplot va bien, pero cuando lo paso a plotly por algún motivo se desconfigura, el subtítulo deja de aparecer y los números que están encima de la barra se mueven, no entiendo porque pasa eso. Les comparto el código.

```
x <- ggplot(balanza_comercial, aes(x=Años,y=value, fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge2",stat = "identity",width = 0.9) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = 0,color = "black", size=3.20,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.85))+
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Accent","Dark2")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from=2006,to=2021,by=1))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,29000))+
  theme(plot.background = element_rect("lightblue"),
        panel.background = element_rect("gray92"),plot.margin = margin(r =0.05,l=0.05),
        panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15), plot.title = element_text(size = 25),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 15), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12.5,angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12.5))+
  labs(title = "Exportaciones por año", subtitle = "En millones de dólares",
       y = "Exportaciones")

ggplotly(x)
```